# Why using .AddNew has no effect on the RecordSet

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to add a new record to an empty RecordSet. The RecordSet is empty because there are no results from the query I'm using to populate it.
This is a piece of the code:

```vb
Set Rsdb = CurrentDbInstance.OpenRecordset("SELECT * from [table1]  WHERE [status]=1", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

Rsdb .AddNew
Rsdb ![firstname].Value = "fname"
Rsdb ![lastname].Value = "lname"
Rsdb ![id_number].Value = 123456
Rsdb ![status].Value = "0"
Rsdb .Update
Rsdb .Requery
```

Since the result of the query is null because table1 doesn't exist, the Rsdb is `Nothing`.
But when I try to use the `.AddNew` nothing gets added.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If the table doesnt exist?

Comment: You cannot add a new record to a table that does not exist. You first need to create that table.

Comment: The `RecordSet is empty because there are no results from the query` and `because table1 doesn't exist, the Rsdb is Nothing` contradict each other. If the former is correct, then your record is added successfully, but when you `Requery`, it is not shown because of the `[status]=1` filter. If the latter is true, then remove that `On Error Resume Next` and create the table first.

Comment: Got it... Thanks for the help